# extracting words using awk

Tags: unix, awk

I have a data file that is made up of lines that all contain FG=???? (where ???? represents a four digit number that is different on each line ).

I would like to extract this from each line and save it to a new file. Is this possible to do using awk?

I have been using the /this/ to extract lines containing the word this. Is there something similar for extracting a word from a line?

Comment: Please provide some example input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You can select a range of characters from each line:

```
awk '{print substr($0,4,4)}' file.txt
```

Specifically for your case:

```
awk -F 'FG=' '{print substr($2,0,4)}' file.txt
```

You can also use `cut`:

```
cut -b4-7 file.txt
```

Comment: I tried this but there isn't a space before the FG so it extracts the whole thing. Sorry I didn't realise this before. So is there a way of extracting part of the word?

Comment: And indeed I didn't use a space in my example, what makes you think that this solution requires a space? Since you tagged your question `unix` I can think about some differences with the Linux version (that I'm using).

Comment: This won't work unless the fileds are actually separated by `=`. Otherwise, awk will take as $2 everything after the first `=`. That is why it is printing the entire line.

Comment: I'm assuming that each line is in the form: `/^FG=[0-9]{4}$/`. The OP doesn't state it explicitly. Anyway I'll update my answer to reflect that case too.

Comment: The substr is a good idea, +1. I edited your answer to print only the 4 characters after the `FG=`.

Answer (score 0):

I could give you a pure awk answer if you post an example of your actual data. In the absence of specific clues, you can always try Perl:

```
perl -ne '/FG=(\d+)/; print "$1\n"'  infile.txt > outfile.txt
```